# No module named 'localstack.mock'

Tags: python, localstack

I have a problem with import from lockalstack

When I try to import 'mock' module from 'lockalstack' library, how it recomend in [README](https://github.com/atlassian/localstack):

```
from localstack.mock import infra
```

I get an error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'localstack.mock'
```

tryed in 0.8.3 and 0.8.6.1 verions

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

ok, problem solved
in another [README](https://github.com/localstack/localstack) on another repo of localstack 
there is another recomends:

```
from localstack.services import infra
```

it works